# VSCode C++ navigate to header file class definition instead of implementation file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Given `classheader.h` containing:

```
class foo_{
private:
    int num;
public:
    int getnum() const;
}
```

and `classimpl.cpp` that contains:

```
#include "classheader.h"

int foo_::getnum() const{
    return num;
}
```

from any other file that calls `foo_`'s `getnum()`, pressing `F12` `(go to definition)` takes one to `classimpl.cpp`. Is there a way to get to the line: `int getnum() const;` in the header file via a shortcut?

Neither of `Peek`'s `Definition` or `Declaration` or `References` seems to take one to the header file.